# Running a classifer on trainset not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, knn

I am using the IRIS dataset (Iris.data)
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/

I first prepared the dataset for classification and then split the data set into training set and test data set

`#Preparing for Data Classification
X = np.array(iris.iloc[:, :-1].values)
Y = np.array(iris.iloc[:, :-1].values)`

`#Splitting the iris data set into the training set and test set 
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =     0.2, random_state = 1)`

I get the error here when

```
#Run the fit using KNeighborsClassifier from sklearn.neighbors.
#First, instantiate the model then, run the classifier on the training set.
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`ValueError                  Traceback (most recent call last)                   <ipython-input-78-7c6d6884854b> in <module>()
2 #First, instantiate the model then, run the classifier on the training set.
3 classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
----> 4 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
5 y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self,  X, y)
777             self.outputs_2d_ = True
778 
--> 779         check_classification_targets(y)
780         self.classes_ = []
781         self._y = np.empty(y.shape, dtype=np.int)~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 171         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
172 
173 
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'`
```

Comment: `import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score`

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'` is indicative of an error in input type. In this specific case, the issue is `Y`. It is continuous and multioutput (i.e., multi-featured), neither of which are appropriate qualities for a classifier.

The reason is that in the first few lines, you are setting `X` and `Y` to the same thing. Your definition of `X` appears correct. However, your definition of `Y` is incorrect and should be changed to `Y = np.array(iris.iloc[:, -1].values)`. (You have an extraneous colon preceding -1.)